# Error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined" on submit form

Tags: joomla-3.x, form, task

I'm getting the following error when trying to submit a form using `Joomla.submitbutton('book.submit')`

The error I get is:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
> at Object.Joomla.submitform (core-uncompressed.js?f096f6025f0c22829d968a68944d3145:66)
> at Object.Joomla.submitbutton (submitbutton.js:26)
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (gallery:195)
> ```

submitbutton.js line 26:

```
if (isValid)
{
    Joomla.submitform(task);
    return true;
}
```

core-uncompressed.js?f096f6025f0c22829d968a68944d3145 line 66:

```
  if (task) {
        form.task.value = task;
  }
```

It means that, somehow, the button is empty or something related to this but I do not understand why.

1. It was perfectly working and now it does not work.
2. The code has not changed at all.
3. I have not touched the project in the past 5 days.
4. It was working when I last checked.

When I went to continue where I left off, I ran into this unpleasant issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `task` field to the form's HTML.

```
<input name="task" type="hidden">
```

Comment: Also the form token has disappeared.